# MS Access: Matching 2 tables with no unique fields

Tags: ms-access, join

I have two tables which look like this:

```
T1:
ID  |  Date  |  Hour

T2:
ID  |  Date  |  Hour
```

I basically need to join these tables when their IDs, dates, and hours match. However, I only want to return the results from `T1` that do not match up with the results in `T2`.

I know this seems simple, but where I'm stuck is the fact that there are multiple rows in `T1` that match up with `T2` (there are multiple intervals for any given hour). I need to return all of these intervals so long as they do not fall within the same hour period in `T2`.

Example data:

T1:

```
1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
1  |  1/1/2011  |  1   
1  |  1/1/2011  |  2
```

T2:

```
1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
1  |  1/1/2011  |  1
```

My expected result set for this would be the last 2 rows from `T1`. Can anyone point me on the right track?

Comment: Maybe adding count on the logic might do it? Since table 1 has 3 duplicates and table 2 has only 2 duplicates.

Comment: You need some way of distinguishing those 3 duplicate records in Table 1.  Without this, I'm afraid you won't get an answer.

Comment: that's sad, thanks for the inputs sir @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: If your tables have row numbers, or other primary key similar to this, then update.

Comment: yeah, if there's a unique field it would be easier, what we are currently doing is matching it manually via excel. which is tedious considering we have thousand records.

Comment: Not a unique field, a _row number_ or primary key.  If we can't address the duplicate records individually, articulating a query becomes difficult.

Comment: Most likely, I would guess that your Excel data isn't structured very well.